# Save search results xcode

Tags: ios, iphone

I am performing various searches and there are four very common searches people are doing.  I would like to preload the results into an array so that new users don't have to wait so long.  How do i save the results so that next time they are already there?

Comment: how you're doing searches is very application specific, can you show some code as to how you are setting up your searches in your app?  Also, get rid of the "xcode" tag in this question as this has to do with iOS and nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: is it a server request? are the results objects or just strings? do you use Core Data in your app? do you already know the results for the searches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you build a cache and it can be implemented as a NSDictionary.

searchTerm can be the key and Results can be the array.

That way, when ever the same searchTerm is used, then return the existing result, if it exists, or go ahead and do the search for the first time and populate the cache.

If you want it to persist across application launches, you can store the cache in user defaults if you want or more elaborate persistence like core data.

Say, your ResultsCache is NSDictionary, then the logic can be

```
if([ResultsCache objectForKey:searchTerm] == nil){
     ResultsArray = [self search:SearchTerm];
     [ResultsCache setObject:ResultsArray forKey:searchTerm];
}


return [ResultsCache objectForKey:searchTerm];
```